# Unexpected results with consecutive + and -

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following queries :

```
SELECT +++++++1;
SELECT +-+-+-+-1;
SELECT --------1;
```

The result is :

```
1
1
Error
```

How is this output explained and why are the first two queries valid and the third not?

Comment: And what do you try to proof?

Comment: @Sergey what do you mean?

Comment: What is the expected result of all these calculations?

Comment: For extra credit: `select 30 / 3 / 5; select 30 / -3 / 5; select 30 / ( -3 ) / 5;`.

Comment: If you posted the error you got, this would have made this less cryptic. Also, I don't doubt your syntax highlighter would have shown you the problem. *Why* you need to prefix a number with 7 plus/negative operators would also help us understand the problem you are *really" trying to solve too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` and `-` are (also) [unary operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/unary-operators?view=sql-server-ver15). So you can indeed chain them, and they are evaluated from right to left:

```
SELECT +(+(+(+(+(+(+1))))));
SELECT +(-(+(-(+(-(+(-1)))))));
```

However, a double hyphen is the [start of a comment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/comment-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) that continues until the end of the line. So when you have a double hyphen, it no longer represents two minus operators...

In your case it leaves your third `select` keyword without anything following it, which is a syntax error.

You can get around that by just separating two consecutive hyphens with a space:

```
SELECT - - - - 1
```

...will output 1.